# Docker container IP 172.17.XXX unable to reach from windows host machine 192.168.X.X

Tags: docker

I have successfully run docker container with default bridge network on ubuntu (Virtual box), I am able to communicate (ping) from My container, but not from my Host os (windows) . virtual box network adapter has bridge

Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to ping from host (windows) too, I think the result is RTO. solution is you need change youre ip to same class as a HOST Windows.